Отправка event при заполнении лога Apache Kafka
Существует приложение на Django, использующее транзакционную обработку потоков. Для исполнения необходимых функций была выбрана Kafka. При заполнении лога необходимо отправлять event, который, в последствии, вызывает необходимый далее функционал.
Каким способом можно отправлять этот event, и возможно ли вовсе? Какие альтернативы можно найти этому способу, если таковые существуют?

Если коротко - не понятно, что вам нужно. Нужно пояснить, что означает "транзакционная обработка потоков", "заполнение лога", "отправлять event", "event вызывает функционал". Попробуйте описать задачу на уровне "что решаем", а не "как решаем". Например, при добавлении заказа с помощью django в БД, асинхронно формировать pdf с подтверждением о покупке, или высылать уведомление почтой пользователю. Ну и уже потом предлагать какой-то свой вариант, если есть.

@Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, прошу прощения за недосказанность. Задача: сжатие записей в базе данных. Есть модель, фиксирующая количество предмета на складе, содержащая записи в формате транзакций, "+1", "-2" и.т.п. Необходимо сжимать эти записи раз в определённое количество времени, для более удобной агрегации. Для этих целей была выбрана Apache Kafka. Идея в том, что при заполнении лога записями транзакций, Kafka должна вызывать функцию, которая бы объединяла эти данные в одно число. Возможно ли с её помощью реализовать указанный функционал?

У транзакций для одного предмета есть порядок или они могут случаться одновременно? Если есть порядок, то не совсем ясно, зачем тут kafka. Сама по себе kafka только хранилище, вызывать она ничего не будет. В целом процедура будет та же. Храните в БД для предмета последнюю транзакцию, которую уже сагрегировали там же, где храните агрегированное значение (если будет использовать кафку - это будет offset последней обработанной транзакции, который нужно будет хранить в БД). С нужной периодичностью запускайте процедуру, которая изменит значение просумировав все несагрегированные транзакции из БД.

Использовать kafka тут имеет смысл только, чтоб сама агрегация не нагружала БД (но это еще нужно проверить будет ли нагружать, плюс для high availability и failover у вас в любом случае должна быть реплика БД, ее можно использовать чтоб не грузить мастер копию) или если хотите делать эту агрегацию в реальном времени. В первом случае точно так же нужно запускать периодически читатель из кафки, во втором он должен слушать постоянно.

Ну и в любом случае использование кафки потребует дополнительной записи в kafka при записи в БД и связанных с этим проблем с атомарностью и целостностью. Боюсь, что не получится выигрыш в производительности, если сделать все правильно.

@Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, нельзя точно сказать, когда появляются транзакции, так как отправляют их клиенты. То бишь, использование кафки в такой ситуации не скажется на производительности?

нельзя точно сказать, когда появляются транзакции, так как отправляют их клиенты - это я не понимаю. Когда появляются транзакции не влияет на то, что я написал выше. Что касается влияния кафки на производительность, то влияние сильно зависит от того, как ее использовать. Если при сохранении в БД еще писать и в кафку, то очевидно, что это медленней, чем просто писать в БД. Насколько сильно влиять и будет ли это заметно/критично - то простая запись скорее всего не будет сильно влиять, но проблема в том, что просто дополнительная запись в кафку не является атомарной.

Простого решиния проблемы с атомарностью нет. Есть варианты со своими компромисами и у каждого свои минусы включая производительность.
